# how to display the data from the database in a template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

i have following model:

```
class comment(models.Model):
    userid=models.CharField(max_length=140)
    apparelid=models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    desc=models.TextField(blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.userid
```

form :

```
class commentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=comment
        exclude=('userid','apparelid',)
```

and view as follows:

```
def comment(request,title_id):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=commentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new=form.save(commit=False)
            new.userid=request.user.username
            new.apparelid=title_id
            new.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            form=commentForm()

    template=loader.get_template('apple3/comment.html')
    context=RequestContext(request,{
                                        'form':form,
                                       }   
                              )   
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

whenever i open my page containg above form it show an error as follows:

```
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:     'function' object has no attribute 'objects'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably import `comment` model from inside your view and then use `comment` again as view name. That's why the error gets thrown.

Please use different name for your view and model if you use them in the same module.

Answer (score 2):

Problem at hand seems to be solved by @mariodev. Additionaly, I'd recommend two following steps as a mean of avoiding similar problems in future:

1. Read [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names), the Style Guide for Python Code **thoroughly**
2. Use only [packages and modules import](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html?showone=Imports#Imports).

Following those two links will make your code more pythonic and less error-prone.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the model **class** and the view **function** is same which is resulting in the error:

```
Exception Value:     'function' object has no attribute 'objects'
```

You may use a different naming conventions for your classes and functions. As per PEP8, first letter of the class name should be capital/uppercase and the function's name should be lowercase.

So in your case, if you have to keep the names exactly same, you may rename your Model Class to **Comment**  and let your view function's name be **comment** and that should solve the problem.